# Rotation of array counter clockwise

Tags: arrays, rotation

For a list, say

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

When somebody says rotate the array anti-/counter-clockwise 2 times, there are two ways to do it:

```
case 1:  1st time: 6,1,2,3,4,5
         2nd time: 5,6,1,2,3,4

case 2:  1st time: 2,3,4,5,6,1
         2nd time: 3,4,5,6,1,2
```

Out of the two cases, which one should I consider?

Comment: It's arbitrary, but I'd consider case 1 to be analogous to "clockwise", and case 2 to be anticlockwise.

Comment: I'd agree with @Blorgbeard. In most cases I consider clockwise to be left-to-right (case 1) and anti-clockwise to be right-to-left (case 2).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider case 2 as Anti-clockwise like bellow:

```
   *
   1
6     2
5     3
   4
```

clock-wise rotation is in the direction `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ... -> 6` like,

```
   *
   6
5     1
4     2
   3
```

And anti-clockwise rotation is in the direction `1 -> 6 -> 5 -> ... -> 2` like.

```
   *
   2
1     3
6     4
   5
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider case 1 as clockwise direction. Because, you are shifting values to right side that is clockwise direction. second case is anti clock wise direction.